# SQL Calendar Table - Adding a WorkDayofMonth Column

Tags: sql, calendar, sql-server-2019

We have an existing Calendar table - but what I want to add is a column which tells me the work day in the month.  For example, with Dec 20201, Wed Dec 1st is the first day so that should be 1, Mon Dec 6th is the fourth workday so that should be 4.

After the 23rd (business day 17), the next business day would be Dec 29th.  And so on, until you hit a new month Jan, where Jan 4th is Day 1 - the first business day of that month.

If I was to add a column "WorkDayofMonth", is there a simple UPDATE I can apply to the calendar table that will assign the value to this new column?

Comment: Different databases will have different syntax but you're looking for the `dayofweek()` or similar function and logic that works for *your* working days. Maybe your table already has a weekday number? A flag for a weekday? As the *sql tag* description suggests, please [TAG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) your RDBMS

Comment: Yes already indicator columns for holidays and workdays (1 or 0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server you could use an updatable CTE, such as

```
alter table Calendar add WorkDayofMonth tinyint null;

with d as (
    select WorkDayofMonth,
      Row_Number() over(partition by CalendarMonth order by CalendarDate) n
    from Calendar
    where isWeekDay = 1 and isHoliday = 0
)
update d set WorkDayofMonth = n;
```

Obviously amending column names as appropriate for your table schema.